# Expected Service Times for truncated exponential

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

I'm trying to solve a problem where all arriving items (arrival exponential $\lambda = 1/5$) are divided into into groups, those who are served within 5 units of time and those who have their service time $>5$. The service of items is also exponential $\mu = 1/5$

So if I want to calculate the mean service time for each group:

$$E[S_1] = \int_0^{5}{s (1/5) e^{-(1/5) s} ds}=(5e-10)/e = 1.32$$
$$E[S_2] = \int_5^{\infty}{s (1/5) e^{-(1/5) s} ds}=10/e = 3.6$$

So before going further, I don't understand why my mean service time for the second group of items is 3.6 when only items with service time $>5$ are considered. Do I have an incorrect approach? Do I need to condition it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $\mu$ = $\frac{1}{5}$ tells you that the mean service time is 5 minutes from 0 to $\infty$.

If you add $E(s_1)$ and $E(s_2)$, it is 5.  One in the interval $ 0-5$ and the other in the interval (5 - $\infty$).

So I am not surprised that the $E(s_2)$ $= \frac{10}{e}$

For truncated exponential, read the above article,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution#Expectation_of_truncated_random_variable

Accordingly, $E(S/S>5) = \dfrac{\int_5^{\infty} sf(s)ds}{1-F(5)}$

The top part you already calculated it to be $\frac{10}{e}$

$F(5) = 1-\frac{1}{e}$

$1-F(5) = \frac{1}{e}$

Now $E(S/S>5) = \dfrac{\frac{10}{e}}{\frac{1}{e}} = 10$ which now makes sense

Comment: thank you for your reply, I really appreciate it. I'm still left wondering if the truncated exponential is the correct mean service time for each group based on the definition of the problem. The formulas I need to use use "mean service time", so is it 10/e or (10/e)/(1/e)?

Comment: It is the latter, (10/e)/(1/e).  I do not know what the underlying problem is, So I do not know what is appropriate. It seems like you have multiple servers and you are trying to channel the arrivals to one of these servers and are analysed separately. If that were to be the case, the above truncated exponential could be of use. If you find the answer useful, you could choose to accept it.

Comment: it's m/g/1 nonpreemtive queue with two groups of customers. So, I need to calculate $E[S]$ and $E[S^2]$ for each group